# finding optimum lambda and features for polynomial regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression

I am new to Data Mining/ML. I've been trying to solve a polynomial regression problem of predicting the price from given input parameters (already normalized within range[0, 1])

I'm quite close as my output is in proportion to the correct one, but it seems a bit suppressed, my algorithm is correct, just don't know how to reach to an appropriate lambda, (regularized parameter) and how to decide to what extent  I should populate features as the problem says : "The prices per square foot, are (approximately) a polynomial function of the features. This polynomial always has an order less than 4".

Is there a way we could visualize data to find optimum value for these parameters, like we find optimal alpha (step size) and number of iterations by visualizing cost function in linear regression using gradient descent.

Here is my code : http://ideone.com/6ctDFh

```
from numpy import *

def mapFeature(X1, X2):
    degree = 2
    out = ones((shape(X1)[0], 1))
    for i in range(1, degree+1):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            term1 = X1**(i-j)
            term2 = X2 ** (j)
            term  = (term1 * term2).reshape( shape(term1)[0], 1 )
            """note that here 'out[i]' represents mappedfeatures of X1[i], X2[i], ..........   out is made to store features of one set in out[i] horizontally """
            out   = hstack(( out, term ))
    return out

def solve():
    n, m = input().split()
    m = int(m)
    n = int(n)
    data = zeros((m, n+1))
    for i in range(0, m):
        ausi = input().split()
        for k in range(0, n+1):
            data[i, k] = float(ausi[k])
    X = data[:, 0 : n]
    y = data[:, n]

    theta = zeros((6, 1))

    X = mapFeature(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
    ausi = computeCostVect(X, y, theta)
    # print(X)
    print("Results usning BFGS : ")
    lamda = 2
    theta, cost = findMinTheta(theta, X, y, lamda)


    test = [0.05, 0.54, 0.91, 0.91, 0.31, 0.76, 0.51, 0.31]
    print("prediction for 0.31 , 0.76 (using BFGS) : ")
    for i in range(0, 7, 2):
        print(mapFeature(array([test[i]]), array([test[i+1]])).dot( theta ))

    # pyplot.plot(X[:, 1], y, 'rx', markersize = 5)
    # fig = pyplot.figure()
    # ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    # ax.scatter(X[:, 1],X[:, 2], s=y) # Added third variable income as size of the bubble
    # pyplot.show()
```

The current output is: 
183.43478288
349.10716957
236.94627602
208.61071682

The correct output should be:
180.38
1312.07
440.13
343.72

Comment: That is not R code. Please add the correct language tag.

Comment: oops , sorry my bad..

Comment: I fixed the indentation and supplied the missing statement **from numpy import * **.  I'm still missing **computeCostVec** and **findMinTheta** to reproduce your output.  Please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: What is the authority or rationale for the expected output?  Is this something you computed independently, or handed down from above (teacher, empirical results, etc.)?

Comment: glad you asked @prune, its a prob on hackerrank - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/predicting-office-space-price, and the full code is available on ideone link i posted...

Comment: Weird.  I don't *see* anything wrong with your implementation.  I ran a set of experiments with various lambdas (powers of 2), and I couldn't find anything better than you got.  Thus, I suspect that there *is* a code problem -- it's not just the lambda value.